# How to run a batch file from another batch file but in a separate process?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run a batch file from another but at the time of doing so I have a problem. The first batch executes the second batch, both of them are in different folders.

But the problem is that when the second batch is executed, **it appears that it was in the first folder**, which is incorrect because the second batch should be in folder B not in the A.
I'm sure the problem is that the first batch is the one that runs everything, so everything else happens as if it were part of the first batch process.

**So how can I solve this problem?**

CHECK THE OUTPUT: [image]

This is my code:

```
-> batch in folder A: start "" C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\FOLDER-B\HERE.bat &

-> batch in folder B: echo WHY AM I STILL IN FOLDER-A ? && pause
```

Comment: You have not instructed either program to do any type of change directory.  The working directory will be Folder A because that is what the parent process set it to.  You are inheriting the entire environment from the parent process. You may want to read the help for the START command.  I bet there is a switch you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you started the batch from folder-A. It doesn't matter where the executable is, it could just as well have been any other executable in the path. If you want to `start` the executable (in this case a batch file) with a starting directory of (wherever that executable resides) then

```
pushd .....folder-B
start "" here.bat ...
popd
```

The `pushd` changes to the required directory, so there's then no need to specify the complete filepath. The `popd` returns to the original directory.

Comment: You could also add this to your answer. `START "" /D "C:\path to folder B" here.bat`

Comment: Thank you Magoo. This worked fine. So this would be like going to folder B and double-clicking on "here.bat" ? Or not?

Comment: @Magoo, well sometimes I feel posting another answer just clutters up things.  No wrong way to do this task really.  I use `PUSHD` a lot and I use `START /D` a lot.  Probably depends on which way the wind is blowing that day.